# Как сохранить изменения из ObservableCollection в базу данных

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml, avalonia

Есть DataGrid, который содержит в себе данные из Observable Collection, полученные из БД.

**viewModel**:

```
Parameters = new ObservableCollection<KrnListValue>((from paramer in db.KrnListValues where paramer.KrnListId == idToCode[value] select paramer).ToList());
```

**View**:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="MainAdminGrid" Grid.Row="0" Margin="20 50 0 0" ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="False" 
                  GridLinesVisibility="All"
                  BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray"
                  RowHeight="25"
                  Height="530"
                  Width="800"
                  
        >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="58" Header="№" Binding="{Binding KrnListValueId}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="190" Header="Код" Binding="{Binding Code}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="300" Header="Значение" Binding="{Binding Value}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Описание" Binding="{Binding Description}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
```

При изменение какой-либо ячейки в таблице ObservableCollection тоже меняется. Я сделал кнопку на сохранение изменений в БД, но не понимаю, как уведомить DbContext() об этих изменениях? Недостаточно просто вызвать метод **db.SaveChanges()**.

Скорее всего нужно биндить не ObesrvableCollection в DataGrid, а сам DbSet. Но у меня не выходит это сделать уже несколько дней.

Comment: [Databinding with WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/databinding/wpf)

Comment: Я не понимаю, как мне оповестить dbContext об изменениях, если привязка даннных в dataGrid идет к observable collection, а не к DbSet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам в комментариях дали правильное решение, его может хватить для большинства задач. Давайте я вам его продемонстрирую.

Допустим у нас есть класс человека:

```
public partial class User : ObservableObject
{
    public int Id { get; init; }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _name;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int _age;
}
```

Так, как вы знакомы с CommunityToolkit, то я тут его использовал. Это простой класс, который содержит в себе некие свойства о человеке, где все свойства кроме ID вызывают `INotifyPropertyChanged`, это сделано для того, чтоб мы могли отслеживать в дальнейшем любые изменения произведенные с объектом где либо.

Имея класс, мы теперь должны сделать `DbContext`, я сделаю что-то такое:

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public AppContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=AppDB.db");
    }
}
```

Ключевое тут `DbSet` - так мы задаем таблицу, которая будет (или уже есть) в базе, все остальное, это "для рабочего примера" так сказать, чтоб не возиться с миграциями и прочим. `EnsureCreated()` проверит наличие базы, и создаст в ней все необходимое (по хорошему использовать миграции). Ну а `UseSqlite()` - у меня SQLite база данных, так я ее подключаю, у вас может быть что-то другое, и может быть за пределами данного класса, это уже не столь важно.

С подключением и прочим покончили, осталось дело за малым, привязка. Я сейчас не буду вдаваться в MVVM, я просто покажу вам простейший пример реализации подобного, а в конце поговорим немного про MVVM. Я напишу в классе окна такой код:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public BindingList<User> Users { get; set; }

    private readonly AppContext _appContext;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        _appContext = new AppContext();

        _appContext.Users.Load();
        Users = _appContext.Users.Local.ToBindingList();
        Users.ListChanged += this.UsersListChanged;
    }

    private void UsersListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e) 
        => _appContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

- `new AppContext();` - мы создаем экземпляр нашего `DbContext` созданного ранее, и сохраняем его в некую переменную чтобы иметь доступ в различных методах к нему.
- `Load()` - Загружаю необходимые мне данные из базы в память. Если нужны конкретные данные, то перед вызовом метода фильтруем данные, например так: `Users.Where(x=>x.Age > 15).Load();`.
- `ToBindingList()` - Мы просим EF отдать нам отслеживаемую коллекцию, которую мы заносим в локальное публичное свойство для привязки. `BindingList` тут для того, чтоб отслеживать изменения самого объекта, если это не важно, и нам нужны лишь добавления/удаления, то можем смело использовать `ObservableCollection`, а из класса убрать INPC.
- `ListChanged` - Подписываемся на все изменения коллекции, и по этому событию просим базу сохранить все данные.

Осталось дело за малым, XAML, в нем нам понадобиться лишь одна строка:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" />
```

Этого достаточно для того, чтоб понять всю работу.

Запускаем, и видим перед собой такое:

[image: Empty List]

Нажимаем на любое пустое поле, заполняем все данные, после заполнения скидываем фокус со строки нажатием, например, на название столбца (чтоб это поведение изменить, попробуйте создать столбцы самостоятельно и у привязки задать соответствующий тип обновления), получаем в итоге такое:

[image: Item Added]

Как видите, ID у нас 1, его задала нам база, открываем базу, и действительно, там есть нужная нам запись:

[image: DB View]

Все, мы тесно связали базу с нашим View, без лишней логики теперь идет автоматическое отслеживание любых изменений, будь то добавление, удаление, редактирование, и т.д.

---

Ну а теперь про тонкости:

1. MVVM - этот подход подразумевает, что вы делите все на мало связанные друг с другом слои, где UI не знает ничего про Model и ViewModel; Model аналогично не знаем про View и ViewModel; ну а ViewModel это связующий слой, который инициализирует Model, получает из него нужные данные, на основе их подготавливает данные для привязок, обрабатывает UI запросы, на основе которых данные отправляются обратно в Model. Вот собственно `User`, `AppContext` - это модель, все, что внутри `MainWindow` (кроме `DataContext`) это ViewModel, все как бы просто, но есть одна маленькая проблема, класс `User` это по сути DTO объект, то есть, не желательно его так напрямую использовать, лучше создать ViewModel обертку, в котором будут только необходимые данные для вывода на экран, а дальше уже делать ручное обновление данных, где по VM событию обновления данных, мы берем измененный VM класс человека, и отправляем в Model (базу) нужные изменения, также и наоборот, мы берем из базы данные, и на их основе заполняем VM коллекцию данными, конвертируя DTO в VM объект человека.
2. Для того, чтоб `DataGrid` давал вам возможность добавлять новые данные (пустая строка снизу), тот класс, что он должен создать (в моем случае `User`) должен быть с пустым конструктором.
3. `_appContext.Dispose()` - EF довольно умный, и сам удалит ненужное за вас, не использовать `Dispose` в данном контексте является нормальной практикой, но вас замучает правда студия предупреждениями) Вообще, я вам советую познать IoC контейнеры, которые за вас будут руководить сроком жизни объекта.

Собственно все, удачи!