# Подробная, актуальная (разжеванная) статья по SQLite в C# и .NET

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, sqlite

Подскажите, пожалуйста, подробную, актуальную, разжеванную статью по SQLite в C#. Хочу научиться добавлять бд в проект и работать с ней, пытался по ютуб видео, но не получается, думаю из-за того, что материал обычно нахожу уже не много не актуальный или пропущены некоторые нюансы.

Comment: Официальную страничку от MS читали? Там буквально небольшая страничка же. И всё актуально: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/?tabs=netcore-cli

Comment: Что будете использовать для работы: чистый ADO.NET, микро-ORM наподобие Dapper или ORM наподобие Entity Framework?

Comment: Ваш вопрос очень общий, в нем нет какой либо конкретики. Определитесь с тем, как именно вы хотите работать с базой, а потом уже спрашивайте конкретно по нужной технологии. Например, вот вам [WPF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1530540/220553) пример с подключенной базой, всего несколько строк кода, отвечает вашем критериям? Ну, вроде да. Короче, вариантов подключения уйма, решите сначала этот вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

https://entityframeworkcore.com/providers-sqlite

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=efcore-8.0&term=SQLite

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/get-started-with-entity-framework-core-using-sqlite/

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore5.com/database-providers/sqlite

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63494481/entity-framework-and-sqlite-the-ultimate-how-to

https://metanit.com/sharp/adonetcore/4.1.php

https://csharp.webdelphi.ru/rabota-s-sqlite-v-c-net-5/

https://www.codeguru.com/dotnet/using-sqlite-in-a-c-application/ :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SQLiteDemo
{
   class Program
   {

      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn;
         sqlite_conn = CreateConnection();
         CreateTable(sqlite_conn);
         InsertData(sqlite_conn);
         ReadData(sqlite_conn);
      }

      static SQLiteConnection CreateConnection()
      {

         SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn;
         // Create a new database connection:
         sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=
            database.db;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;");
         // Open the connection:
         try
         {
            sqlite_conn.Open();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {

         }
         return sqlite_conn;
      }

      static void CreateTable(SQLiteConnection conn)
      {

         SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
         string Createsql = "CREATE TABLE SampleTable
            (Col1 VARCHAR(20), Col2 INT)";
         string Createsql1 = "CREATE TABLE SampleTable1
            (Col1 VARCHAR(20), Col2 INT)";
         sqlite_cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
         sqlite_cmd.CommandText = Createsql;
         sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         sqlite_cmd.CommandText = Createsql1;
         sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      }

      static void InsertData(SQLiteConnection conn)
      {
         SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
         sqlite_cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
         sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO SampleTable
            (Col1, Col2) VALUES ('Test Text ', 1);";
         sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO SampleTable
            (Col1, Col2) VALUES ('Test1 Text1 ', 2);";
         sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO SampleTable
            (Col1, Col2) VALUES ('Test2 Text2 ', 3);";
         sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


         sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO SampleTable1
            (Col1, Col2) VALUES ('Test3 Text3 ', 3);";
         sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      }

      static void ReadData(SQLiteConnection conn)
      {
         SQLiteDataReader sqlite_datareader;
         SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
         sqlite_cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
         sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SampleTable";

         sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();
         while (sqlite_datareader.Read())
         {
            string myreader = sqlite_datareader.GetString(0);
            Console.WriteLine(myreader);
         }
         conn.Close();
      }
   }
}
```

**А вот тут прямо всё** (см. меню справа): https://stuartsplace.com/information-technology/programming/c-sharp/c-sharp-and-sqlite-introduction

В общем, поиск в Гугле работает нормально.