# Как сделать функцию редактирования данных в двух таблицах Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Есть две таблицы в базе данных: Student и Marks. Они связаны между собой по id(pk) и studentId(fk). Нужно сделать функцию, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "редактировать" можно было редактировать данные в двух таблицах. При нажатии на строку в datagridview данные строки отображаются в нескольких textbox на форме. После редактирования данных в textbox нужно нажать на кнопку редактировать и данные должны сохраниться и обновиться в datagridview

Comment: Привязки (binding) + что-то типа [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1530540/220553) (внимание на `ToBindingList()`), ну и + [загрузка связанных данных](https://metanit.com/sharp/efcore/3.3.php), все, у вас  готовое решение.